# Please help identify this plant

Tags: identification

Can someone please help identify this plant? Pictures below.
[image: profile]
[image: leaves_closeup]
[image: seed]

The plant has red "poofy" flowers which I don't have pictures of unfortunately. Someone identified this as bottlebrush (callistemon), but I now think that may have been a misidentification for the following reasons:

1. The leaves (closeup above) are pretty differently shaped than what an image-search for "bottlebrush" turns up.
2. The overall "profile" of the tree looks pretty different, I think, than image-search results for "bottlebrush."
3. Image searches on "bottlebrush" show the red flowers as somewhat elongated, but mine were more spherical, not really elongated at all.

I'd be grateful if someone knowledgeable out there can correctly identify this plant. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Calliandra, most likely Calliandra haemotocephala; common names include powder puff, red powder puff or fairy duster. It's hardy in Zones 9-11 in the USA http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a493

Answer (score 0):

Does it have squarishh (quadrilateral) branches and gorgeous fall color? Sure looks a lot like Burning Bush.

Comment: Just googled "burning bush" and no - that's not my plant: mine does not turn that beautiful red in fall. Leaves remain green all year, and it just sprouts a few "poofy" spherical red flowers. I'm pretty sure @Bamboo correctly identified the plant as Calliandra. Image search results of "calliandra" pretty much exactly match what I have.